# json from string to array using php

Tags: php, json, facebook, curl

I have a problem with json parsing.
I have already read the many questions here on stackoverflow but I can't figured out what I'm missing.

In my site I use Facebook Api to post my feed using curl and it respond with a json message.
I take this response and I save it in my database.
In my Backoffice I need to retrieve this message and print it in case of error.

Here an example about an error message:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":1500}}
```

In my php page I need to get just the `message` part so I did:

```
$message = get from the db and fetch;
$error_array = json_decode($message,true);
print_r($error_array);
```

but it doesn't print anything, just a blank page.
If I just print `$message` I can see the entire string.

What am I missing?
This issue it's driving me crazy all day long!!

Comment: You do not have `JSON` functionality enabled for your PHP installation

Comment: quite possible, if he is using PHP version < 5.2

Comment: The problem was a bad encoding of the data when I retrieve it from the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following:

```
<pre>
<?php

$jsonStr = '{"error":{"message":"(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid","type":"OAuthException","code":1500}}';

$error_array = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

print_r($error_array);

?>
```

and getting output:

```
Array
(
    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] => (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 1500
        )
)
```

It's working as intended.

I suspect the problem is with this:

`$message = get from the db and fetch;`

After you load the `$message` variable, do a `var_dump($message)` and see if the string is in there (as expected).

Comment: it is the answer. your provided JSON string is perfectly valid. so the only reason your code does not work is that you get the wrong output from your DB. Possibly because of html entity encoding or something similar

Comment: if he doesn't have `json_encode` or `json_decode` functionality in his PHP, he would have gotten a `function not exists` error - which would have been shown on page (if display_error is on) or logged to file (if error_log is enabled).

Comment: Thanks Latheesan Kanes the problem was the encoded string, when I retrieve the data from the db I get the double quotes parsed so it caused the errors.
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

$jsonString = '["m@gmail.com","b@gmail.com","c@gmail.com"]';
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString);

Or

$jsonString = "[\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\",\"c@gmail.com\"]";
$arrayOfEmails=json_decode($jsonString);